# Get Ajax to open modal, make PHP function call and place results inside the modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, modal-dialog

All night I have been playing with how to achieve this but can not figure it out. On click I am asking an AJAX call to open a modal and make a PHP function call. I want the results of that PHP function call to open inside the modal.

I have moved the script around, tried adding it to the AJAX request itself, tried making the .show on teh script inside the PHP. I am missing something but could use some help.

I know that the PHP function is being called via AJAX because in the console I will see the result. The modal however does not open on the page. **The modal itself will not open**

**ONCLICK CALL**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button seated-btn" onclick="toptions('+val.wait_id+')" data-id="'+val.wait_id+'">
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
function toptions(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
    action: 'options'
            },      
    success: function (data) {
    ("#myModal").show()
             ;}
        }); 
    }
```

**PHP FUNCTION**

```
    function options(){ 
    global $wpdb;
    global $available;
    $check_availability = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT  `id` FROM mytablename "));
    if (!empty($check_availability)){
     foreach($check_availability as $available){echo "ID Number" . str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5) . $available->id. "<br>\n";
        }
    }
else {echo "No Available";};
        ?>
    
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>
    
    </div>
    <script>
    jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
    });
    </script>
            <?php
    }
```

**THE HTML**

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p> <!-- HERE IS WHERE  I WANT THE PHP RESULTS TO SHOW--></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: where you use  `action: options` in PHP function??

Comment: it calls the PHP function

Comment: what you get in `action` in `function options(){}`

Comment: How do you mean? in the action it is calling the PHP function which does work. What it doesnt do is launch the modal. I do get the proper response in the console however.

Comment: what do you see inside console ? Also that modal is on which page on calling page ?

Comment: wait, you’re sending back the html for the modal, as well as javascript to activate it? I would have the modal already in the html, and use the ajax response to fill in and activate it. I personally only send json vis ajax.

Comment: FYI, your ajax doesn’t call a php function. You’ve completely misunderstood why ajax is used: php is only executed on the server, not in the browser. ajax is the same as submitting a form back to the server, just in the background so your page doesn’t refresh.  Your action should point to a url. Take a look at the source listing of the html in your browser; you won’t see the php code, because it was parsed back on the server and doesn’t exist by the time your browser renders the html.

Comment: @timmorton thanks then what is the solution/ better way? I keep changing the code to follow as others have suggested which I feel gets it farther off. When you mention having the modal in the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

You need to add `id` to `<p>` tag where you want to add php response from ajax.

**AJAX CALL**

```
    function toptions(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: {
        action: 'options'
                },      
        success: function (data) {
        $("#myModal").show();
        $("#my-data").html(data); //Add this line
}
            }); 
        }
```

**THE HTML**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p id="my-data"> <!-- HERE IS WHERE  I WANT THE PHP RESULTS TO SHOW--></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! That makes sense about the ID in the <p> tag. The model itself however is not opening at all. I m wondering about the launching of the modal and its script if I have it in the right place inside the PHP function and if when the PHP function is called if it will run the script with the HTML?

Comment: To show modal , in success callback, try replacing `$("#myModal").show();` to `$("#myModal").modal('show');`